# Getting factors of a number with least sum in O(1)

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find the factor pair of a number with least sum in O(1).

Here is the explanation :

```
If number is 100. Then all the possible pairs are :

1    X  100
2    X  50
4    X  25
5    X  20
10   X  10
20   X  5
25   X  4
50   X  2
100  X  1
```

Here the pair with least sum is 10,10 which is clearly the middle one

```
Similarly if number is 12 then pairs are as follows

1  X  12
2  X  6
3  X  4
4  X  3
6  X  2
12 X  1
```

Here the required pair is either 3,4 or 4,3.

```
If a number has 'p' pairs then the required one is always ceil(p/2).
```

If the given number is a perfect square then the task is pretty simple.The pair would be just `sqrt(number),sqrt(number).`

If not then the pair would be either `ceil(sqrt(number)),number/ceil(sqrt(number))`

`given that ceil(sqrt(number)) is a factor of number`

**or** the `immediate factor neighbour of sqrt(number):`

For example consider '6'. 6 is not a perfect square.

ceil of sqrt(6) is 3 and 3 is a factor of 6.So the required pair is `3,6/3=2`

```
Now consider 102. All pairs are :

1  *  102.0
2  *  51.0
3  *  34.0
6  *  17.0
17  *  6.0
34  *  3.0
51  *  2.0
102 *  1
```

The required pair in this is 17,6 or 6,17. `Here ceil(sqrt(102)) is 11`. The immediate factor neighbour of 11 is 17 or 6. `Now this is what we actually find.`

**How do we find that immediate factor neighbour ?**

Here is my O(n) implementation :

```
import math

l = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if n % i is 0:
        l.append(i)
middle = l[math.ceil(len(l) / 2)]
print("Required pair is ", middle, ",", n / middle)
```

Comment: What's with the `java` tag?

Comment: by mistake I added it

Comment: I find this an interesting question, I upvoted it :)

Comment: yes it is interesting. It just requires to brainstorm that's it. I'm sure that there would be a solution

Comment: For any integer? How about primes?

Comment: It could be easily solved in O(sqrt(n)), and getting the biggest divizor <= sqrt(n) within a for loop, still searching for O(1)

Comment: I dont think it is possible unless you say finding the squareroot of a number is O(1) which it isnt.

Comment: @bharath Ignore primes? Sounds just silly. Then I'll just give you a prime multiplied with 2.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that O(1) might be possible?

Comment: @bharath That's not what I asked. Please answer what I did ask.

Comment: @bharath "**ceil of 6 is 3** and **3 is a multiple of 6**". No, ceil of 6 is 6. And 3 is not a multiple of 6.

Comment: @bharath Huh? Print the prime number twice? And I didn't ask for primes.

Comment: Important note: To look for the closest divisor to sqrt(n) doesn't actually help, because we don't know to do that in O(1). If we could, than we would be able to easily do integer factorization. More info here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376860/closest-divisor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the proof that finding the pair must at least be as hard as integer factoring (which implies there is no known O(1) algorithm):

If we start with a number N and get the pair with the smallest sum, as it was shown, the divisors are the closest to the sqrt(N) so there only 2 possibilities:
1. The pair is 1 - N which means N is a prime. Which is the trivial case.
2. We found some non-trivial divisor k. Which means we can apply the algorithm successively for k and N/k, eventually finding all the prime divisors efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

I can also only think of a O(sqrt(n)) method

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

m = 200

for i in range(ceil(sqrt(m)), 0, -1):
    if m % i == 0:
        print(i, int(m / i))
        break
```

we got 10, 20

we know that

```
(a - b)^2 >= 0
```

then we got

```
a^2 + b^2 >= 2ab
```

for our case

```
x + m/x
```

we have

```
x + m/x >= 2sqrt(m)
```

so we got the boundary of the min(sum(x + m/x)), the min sum should be generated by the two factors that are very close to sqrt(m); the math problem behind is x + m/x function, when x = sqrt(m), sum(x + m/x) is minimize, but due to we need x and m/x both be integers, so we should try to find the ones closest to sqr(m).

Answer (score 1):

Not `O(n)` but you can reduce the time complexity using the following program

```
from math import *

val = floor(sqrt(n))
l2 = []
for i in range(val,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        l2.extend([i,n//i])
        break

print(l2)
```

Here we are basically calculating the square root of the number, and checking if it is a factor of the given input. We increment by 1 until we find the first factor. The pair of that factor and resulting quotient has the smallest sum.

A speed comparison for the two programs

```
from math import *
from time import time

n = 1120304

t0 = time()
l = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if n % i is 0:
        l.append(i)

middle = l[math.ceil(len(l) / 2)]
# print("Required pair is ", middle, ",", n / middle)

t1 = time()
val = floor(sqrt(n))
l2 = []
for i in range(val,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        l2.extend([i,n//i])
        break

t2 = time()

t1-t0 # 0.1386280059814453
t2-t1 # 0.009765148162841797
```

Comment: This is an O(sqrt(n)) solution, not really what OP asked for.

Comment: @TheJavatar, I know. I mention time reduction in the answer and not `O(1)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question is a new question. I have seen some similar questions 
since many years ago but never saw an `O(1)` solution.

So let's face the reality, `O(sqrt(n))` may be the best situation.

Comment: Probably it's correct.Take a look at Menglog Li's answer. Its some what less than O(sqrt(n)) complexity